# Set SignalR key expiration time when using Redis Backplane in farm

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, signalr

I have server farm with 2 servers and an application developed in ASP.NET Core 3.1 which is using SignalR. I had problems with the signals so I implemented the [Redis backplane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and everything works fine now. This is the code from Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
 {
   option.Configuration = "127.0.0.1:6379;
   option.InstanceName = "InstanceName";
 });

 services.AddSignalR(o =>
 {
    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
 }).AddStackExchangeRedis("127.0.0.1:6379");
```

The problem here is that the keys which are recorded in the Redis server have no expiration time and they will stay there forever. Example:

[image]

Is there any way I can set the expiration time for these keys?
Or maybe there is some default configuration which is managing these keys?

Comment: Does [this article](https://redis.io/commands/TTL) useful to you ?

Comment: @JasonPan not really. I need some code configuration for this, not console commands.

Comment: If set ttl, the k-v will expired, does the effect is you want ?